# Is there a database that I can look up a specific question and find all the תשובות from all the rabbis over the centuries?

Tags: jewish-books

I know there is Bar-Ilan and Otzer Hachochmah, but is there a database that can search all תשובות with key words? Thanks!

Comment: Otzar is based upon OCR scanned seforim.  You can search based on key words there but the precision won't be perfect due to the limited accuracy of the OCR.  On Bar-Ilan you can do more precise searches with key words, word roots and other search criteria.  While they have a massive amount of seforim digitized, Otzar might have more total seforim at this point.

Comment: There are various reference works that can be helpful. You have to find the right one for each topic though.

Comment: It's called Yabia Omer